# ¿Como hacer balance de carga con docker swarm?

Tags: docker

Quería preguntaros, sí hay algun metodo que tenga docker swarm para poder hacer balance de carga, porque sí scalo los servicios la misma istancia se duplica también en el nodo worker pero en el momento que yo desconecto el nodo master deja de funcionar todos los servidores.

Uso DNS,FTP,APACHE,MYSQL,WORDPRESS.

¿Alguna idea para poder tener los 2 nodos en balance de carga?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un proxy inverso para hacer el balanceo.

Yo estoy probando [Traefik](https://traefik.io/).

Con un docker-compose.yml como este, desplegas con **docker stack deploy** en todos los swarm:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/local/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      mode: global

networks:
  traefik-net:
    driver: overlay
    external: true
```

Esto te estará escuchando en el puerto 80 y 8080 (información del docker traefik).

Observa que le paso la configuración a traefik dejando la en */var/local/traefik/traefik.toml*. Echale un vistazo a la [documentación de traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/) para ver las opciones.

La configuración que estoy utilizando es como esta:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

[entryPoints.traefik]
address = ":8080"


[api]

entryPoint = "traefik"
dashboard = true
debug = true

logLevel = "DEBUG"
[accessLog]

################################################################
# Docker configuration backend
################################################################

# Enable Docker configuration backend.
[docker]

endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "docker.localhost"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = true
usebindportip = true
swarmMode = true
network = "traefik"
```

Fijate que estoy usando una red *overlay* que se llama traefik-net. En esa red es donde voy a asociar los contendores de mis aplicaciones.

Por ejemplo para desplegar una aplicación via traefik uso un docker-composer.yml como este:

```
version: '3'

services:
  miapp:
    image: miapp
    ports:
      - "80"
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.port: 80
        traefik.docker.network: traefik-net
        traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:miapp.com"
networks:
  traefik-net:
    external: true
```

Lo interesante es en la parte deploy las labels que le pongo. Estas las lee traefik y se auto configura. Cuando le entra una petición a miapp.com traefik la redirige al contenedor apropiado.
Si tienes varios contendores myapp, lo redirigira a uno de ellos.

Por otro lado tengo un dns donde tengo una entrada myapp.com apuntando a cada traefik.